# Use primary and secondary DNS servers in parellel for name resolutions

Tags: c++, qt, networking, dns

I am using the following API's for making a HTTP request.

```
QNetworkRequest Request (QUrl (QString (HTTP_PRF PING_URL)));
m_pNetworkReply = m_pNetAccesMgr->get (Request);
```

My resolv.conf has the following entries.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 10.10.182.225
```

It seems that the `QNetworkAccessManager's` get API uses the nameservers sequentially to resolve the given domain name, i.e it tries `8.8.8.8` first, and if it fails it tries `10.10.182.255`. Is there some way to make Qt to do this name resolution parallely.

Comment: I do not think you can. You are supposed to use the second one only if the first fails, so I doubt there are any option to just enable to get parallel requests. However you could resolve it yourself using `QDnsLookup` and manually doing 2 lookups. May I ask why you want to do them in parallel?

Comment: @Benjamin: Due to certain limitations, I have to use `8.8.8.8` as the first entry in my `resolv.conf`. But some routers that have captive portal are blocking `8.8.8.8` until signed-in. In such routers, my DNS lookup takes 5+ seconds for the first name lookup.

Answer (score 3):

I am no network expert, but it looks like a problem that would better be solved system wise than just by tweaking a single program.

According to [Adjusting how long Linux takes to fail over to backup DNS server listed in resolv.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/562079/adjusting-how-long-linux-takes-to-fail-over-to-backup-dns-server-listed-in-resol), you can add this line to `resolv.conf`:

```
options timeout:1 attempts:1
```

This will set the timeout to 1s, switch dns server after first failed attempt.

Comment: 1 second is a huge delay compared the expected ~8ms for a DNS lookup

Comment: @Navin A fast DNS lookup generally takes tens of milliseconds. Slower, uncached DNS lookups can take hundreds of ms. Worst cases can take multiple seconds. That's why system timeouts are often configured with values of multiple seconds. For instance Windows will contact the 2nd server after 1s and contact gain the first server after another 2s. On Linux the default timeout is 5s. So no 1s is not huge and 8ms is not an expected delay for a DNS lookup.